# Google Chart Timeline floating X-axis

Tags: google-visualization, timeline

How can I set floating X axis in Timeline? My list is very long, and I see the timeline after scrolling. I would like to show timeline always at the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a height on either the Timeline's container or in its options, the chart will draw with an internal scroll bar, giving the x-axis a fixed position at the bottom of the chart.

```
function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['Name', 'Start', 'End'],
        ['Foo', new Date(2014, 0, 1), new Date(2014, 0, 2)],
        ['Bar', new Date(2014, 0, 3), new Date(2014, 0, 6)],
        ['Cad', new Date(2014, 0, 2), new Date(2014, 0, 3)],
        ['Qud', new Date(2014, 0, 7), new Date(2014, 0, 10)],
        ['Fiz', new Date(2014, 0, 4), new Date(2014, 0, 9)],
        ['Buz', new Date(2014, 0, 4), new Date(2014, 0, 5)],
        ['Baz', new Date(2014, 0, 3), new Date(2014, 0, 6)],
        ['Piz', new Date(2014, 0, 4), new Date(2014, 0, 6)],
        ['Pop', new Date(2014, 0, 2), new Date(2014, 0, 8)]
    ]);

    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(document.querySelector('#chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, {
        height: 300,
        width: 600
    });
}
google.load('visualization', '1', {packages: ['timeline'], callback: drawChart});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/z18ruap9/

Comment: Yes, but it is the same, than we use a style inside the <div>.

Comment: It should be exactly the same if you style the div: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/z18ruap9/1/

Comment: Yes, but I have thought a line(x axis), that "slides" always to the exact data line.

Comment: Oh, that's different.  The API does not support what you want, but it *may* be possible to use CSS/javascript to alter the inner structure of the Timeline to get the effect you want.